# Want to convert this JSON data into readable text and store in MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Below is the data which is stored in a JSON file and I need to read the below data using PHP and after reading I want to store it in MySQL.

```
{
    "CONTACTDETAILS": [
    {
        "checkList_Id_PointNo": "1",
        "checkList_Name": "Substation earthing layout clearly making the position or earthing pits with identification number and the route of earthing lead / strip",
        "checkList_Status": "OK",
        "checkList_Remark": "Remark ",
        "checkList_Photo": "11EarthingDG Earthing1"
    },
    {
        "checkList_Id_PointNo": "2",
        "checkList_Name": "All earhting pits should have identification number as indicated in earthing layout written over them with permanent paint",
        "checkList_Status": "Not OK",
        "checkList_Remark": "Remark 2",
        "checkList_Photo": "11EarthingDG Earthing2"
    },
    {
        "checkList_Id_PointNo": "3",
        "checkList_Name": "Earthing pits should be clean and no unwanted material or vegetation should be present in the pits",
        "checkList_Status": "Not Applicable",
        "checkList_Remark": "Remark 5",
        "checkList_Photo": "11EarthingDG Earthing3"
    },
    {
        "checkList_Id_PointNo": "4",
        "checkList_Name": "Earthing pit chamber should be painted and plastered on both surfaces",
        "checkList_Status": "OK",
        "checkList_Remark": "Yyyyyyy",
        "checkList_Photo": "11EarthingDG Earthing4"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to try decode this json formate by using function `json_decode($jsonVariable)`
or follow this link [JSON_DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) . This function convert into array and they print by using `foreach` loop

Comment: See php documentation for `foreach` examles.

Comment: follow the link already mention in my answer. Hop you will understand. and please up vote my answer